swiftui bottom padding has no effect on a geometryreader view component
I was following the Swiftui tutorial at section 6 (https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/creating-and-combining-views)
to use a circle image to create an overlapping effect on the map. Turns out that when using a GeometryReader, the bottom padding was not working at all:
VStack{
        MapView().frame(height:300)
        
        CircleImage()
            .offset(y: -130)
            .padding(.bottom, -130)
        
        VStack(alignment:.leading){
            Text(
                "Turtle Rock"
            )
            .font(
                .title
            )
            
            HStack {
                Text(
                    "Joshua Tree National Park"
                )
                .font(
                    .subheadline
                )
                Spacer()
                Text(
                    "California"
                )
                .font(
                    .subheadline
                )
            }
        }.padding(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/10/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
    }

This is the code for the CicleImage view:
GeometryReader(content: {
geometry in
            let _ = print(
                geometry.size.width
            )
            AsyncImage(
                url: URL(
                    string: "https://cms.rationalcdn.com/v3/assets/blteecf9626d9a38b03/bltf5486c52361f2012/6144fafd39dff133fc23de9f/img-ios.png"
                )
            )
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
            .clipShape(
                Circle()
            ).overlay{
                Circle().stroke(
                    .white,
                    lineWidth: 4
                )
            }.shadow(
                radius: 7
            )
        })

Overall output:

Why is that the bottom padding has no effect on a geometryreader view component??
